# Perl: output checking routine returns wrong status

Tags: perl, scripting

Good day, everyone!

I'm almost ignorant in Perl, but have to deal with a script that is designed to process the output of several system check commands for Celerra NAS. One of the routines always returns "2" in the $rc variable, while as far as I can tell it should be "0".

Here is the part of the script that is designed to deal with the output:

```
#(7) Subroutine to handle 'enclosure_status -v -e 0'
#    Sample command output:
# DEVICE A                         DEVICE B
#---------------ENCLOSURE ALARMS----------------
# Pass        PSA OK               Pass
sub enclosure_status {
#   Find column positions given variable word count, space delimited output
    $deva_ix=index($result[1],"DEVICE A");  
    $devb_ix=index($result[1],"DEVICE B");  
    $msg="";
    $rc=-1;
    $skip=1;    # skip items other than alarms & errors
    foreach (@result) {
    if ($deva_ix eq -1) { last; }   # command output not as expected
    if (length($_) < $devb_ix+4) { next; }      # blank line
    if ($_ =~ m/------/) {      # process block header
        if ($rc eq -1) { $rc=0; }
        if ($_ =~ /ALARM/) { $skip=0; next; }
        if ($_ =~ /ERRORS/) { $skip=0; next; }
        if ($_ =~ /FRU STATUS/) { $skip=0; next; }
        $skip=1; next; }
    if ($skip eq 1) { next; }
        if (substr($_,$deva_ix,4) eq "Pass" 
        and substr($_,$devb_ix,4) eq "Pass") { next; }
        $rc=2;
        if ($msg ne "") { $msg = $msg . ", "; }
    $msg = $msg . $_;
        } # end foreach
    if ($rc eq 0) {
        $msg="All alarms are in condition Pass"; }
    elsif ($rc<0) {
        $rc=3; $msg="Unexpected results from command " . $parm[1]; }
    &print_results($host,$parm[0],$rc,$msg);
    } # end subroutine
```

And this is the part of the output of the command:

```
    DEVICE A                         DEVICE B
-------------------PRESENCE--------------------
 00 60 16 43 C7 EB    MAC     00 60 16 43 C9 85
 Scorpion    Hardware Platform    Scorpion
 Present     Peer Compute Blade   Present
 Present     Compute Blade        Present
 Powered On  Compute Blade        Powered On
 Present     Power Supply A       Present
 Present     Power Supply B       Present
 Inactive    Manufacturing Mode   Inactive
 Inactive    Margin High Mode     Inactive
 Inactive    Margin Low Mode      Inactive
 Inactive    MP I2C Bus in Reset  Inactive
---------------BROADCOM STATUS-----------------
 Active      Dnlink/P4 FullDuplex Active
 Active      Dnlink/P4 100 MBPS   Active
 Active      Dnlink/P4 Up         Active
 Active      PeerSP/P3 FullDuplex Active
 Active      PeerSP/P3 100 MBPS   Active
 Active      PeerSP/P3 Up         Active
 Active      Uplink/P1 FullDuplex Active
 Active      Uplink/P1 100 MBPS   Active
 Active      Uplink/P1 Up         Active
 Active      SP    /P0 FullDuplex Active
 Active      SP    /P0 100 MBPS   Active
 Active      SP    /P0 Up         Active
---------------ENCLOSURE ALARMS----------------
 Pass        PSA OK               Pass
 Pass        PSA Overtemp         Pass
 Pass        PSA AC OK            Pass
 Pass        PSB OK               Pass
 Pass        PSB Overtemp         Pass
 Pass        PSB AC OK            Pass
----------------BROADCOM ALARMS----------------
 Pass        5325 Comm Status     Pass
 Pass        5325 MIB RAM         Pass
 Pass        5325 MIN MEM         Pass
 Pass        5325 BUFF Con        Pass
--------------RESUME CSUM ERRORS---------------
 Pass        PSA Csum Error       Pass
 Pass        PSB Csum Error       Pass
 Pass        CB x Csum Error      Pass
 Pass        Midplane Csum Error  Pass
 Pass        Resume Read Timeout  Pass
----------------COLDFIRE ALARMS----------------
 Pass        P On Self Flash Status Pass
 Pass        P On Self RAM Status  Pass
 Pass        P On Self FEC Status  Pass
 Pass        P On Self 5325 Status  Pass
 Pass        Run Self Flash Status  Pass
 Pass        Run Self RAM Status  Pass
 Pass        Diag 5325 Status     Pass
 Pass        Encl Resume Block    Pass
 Pass        Peer RS232 traffic   Pass
 Pass        MidPlane ID Read     Pass
 Pass        I2C Arbit Error      Pass
 Pass        I2C MP Bus Error     Pass
-------------STATUS CONDITIONS-----------------
 Valid       Peer Coldfire Status Valid
 Valid       Fault Expander       Valid
 Valid       Data Mover Status    Valid
 Valid       PSB Status           Valid
 Valid       PSA Status           Valid
------------------FRU STATUS-------------------
 Pass        FRU CPU DIMM 0       Pass
 Pass        FRU CPU DIMM 1       Pass
 Pass        FRU CPU DIMM 2       Pass
 Pass        FRU CPU DIMM 3       Pass
 Pass        FRU CPU Module       Pass
 Pass        FRU CPU IO Module    Pass
 Pass        NAS Personality Card Pass
 Pass        FRU Enclosure        Pass
 Pass        FRU Coldfire         Pass
 Pass        FRU Power Supply B   Pass
 Pass        FRU Power Supply A   Pass
---------------SYSTEM VARIABLES----------------
 02          Slot ID              03
 00          Enclosure ID         00
 00          BackPlane ID         01
 61          Post Code            61
 05          Reason Code          05
 2C          Blade Status Code    2C
 80          Post Middle 8 bits   80
 00          I2C Error Mask       00
 00          I2C MP Error Mask    00
```

The script forms a message to be sent to a server, and here is how it looks like:

```
emcns120        Alarms  2        Pass P On Self Flash Status Pass, Pass P On Self RAM Status Pass, Pass P On Self FEC Status Pass, Pass P On Self 5325 Status Pass, Pass Run Self Flash Status Pass
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your assumption that the Pass/Fail status
is always in the same column is violated.  If you look carefully at 
your COLDFILE ALARMS, you'll see that in some cases, the final status 
is pushed out by a space, causing your routine to fail.

I would suggest splitting the lines on spaces in the sections you
care about and always comparing
the first word in the line and the last word with "Pass" to see if
everything is correct.  Here's the updated code:

```
sub enclosure_status {
$msg="";
$rc=-1;
$skip=1;    # skip items other than alarms & errors
foreach (@result) {
if ($_ =~ m/------/) {      # process block header
    if ($rc eq -1) { $rc=0; }
    if ($_ =~ /ALARM/) { $skip=0; next; }
    if ($_ =~ /ERRORS/) { $skip=0; next; }
    if ($_ =~ /FRU STATUS/) { $skip=0; next; }
    $skip=1; next; }
if ($skip eq 1) { next; }
@words = split;
if ($words[0] eq "Pass" && $words[-1] eq "Pass") { next; }
    $rc=2;
    if ($msg ne "") { $msg = $msg . ", "; }
$msg = $msg . $_;
    } # end foreach
if ($rc eq 0) {
    $msg="All alarms are in condition Pass"; }
elsif ($rc<0) {
    $rc=3; $msg="Unexpected results from command " . $parm[1]; }
&print_results($host,$parm[0],$rc,$msg);
} # end subroutine
```

I've tried to stick to your style above.

Comment: Thanks for the code! It worked!!! I believe that it would take me quite a time to rewrite this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well... There seems to be some array called `@result` hopefully containing strings. And for each of those strings, you check whether the two four letter substrings starting at `$deva_ix` and `$devb_ix` equal the string `"Pass"` and if, even once, either does not, you end with `$rc` equaling 2.

Curiously though, `$deva_ix` and `$devb_ix` are set to be the position of the Substrings `"DEVICE A"` and `"DEVICE B"` in the second string in `@result`. And while headers containing `------` and sections not having either of `"ALARM"`, `"ERROR"` or `"FRU STATUS"` in their header are skipped, your sample file (i'll just assume that those lines are stored in `@result`) is either incomplete or incompatible as it does not have the Device names in its second line.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake: I provided only a sample, and not the complete output. I edited my question, so it is there now. I believe, that the problem is in the lines "Pass P On Self Flash Status Pass" and the other five, they are to long probably, but how to edit the script to make it work?

Comment: Yep, they would certainly fail. Does it work if you remove them for a testrun? Because it still seems as if "Device A" and "Device B" are not aligned with the "Pass" columns. And while i do not know how `@result` is populated, it expects them in the second, not the first of its entries. If you want to make it work on unaligned lines, you would need to change the whole "Pass"-searching logic. And it would require aditional knowledge. For example, what is the opposite of "Pass"? "Fail"? And can either show up in the text between the two columns?

Comment: Thanks for your hints! The were very helpful indeed.